# DesktopAppConverter (DAC) says the expanded image is invalid, when I try to convert my app

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I have downloaded the .wim file that matches my Windows version (14393) and gone through the process of setting up the converter. So, I have the converter app running on my machine. When I attempt to run a conversion, I get error message E_EXPANDED_BASEIMG_INVALID. I have tried to get rid of the expanded image by run DAC with the -Cleanup ExpandedImage parameter, but it fails to clear it. Have you managed to replace the expanded image? The files are quite large and I cannot keep adding expanded images to my machine. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: What error do you meet when you use the -Cleanup ExpandedImage command to deletes the expanded base image? Could you please try to use this -Cleanup All command to see if it works?
For more information, please check this artcle:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/id-id/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter .

Comment: @Fang Peng     I ran the converter with "-Cleanup All" and logged to a file. There appears to be a missing command (or path), judging by the following extract from my log: DesktopAppConverter : 
Inner Exception[0]:
System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: error 'E_DELETE_DAC_CONTAINER_NETWORK_FAILED': Failed to delete container network created by desktop app converter. See inner exception for more details. ---> System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'Get-ContainerNetwork' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Comment: Needless to say that the image folders are all still there. If this command runs successfully, would it get rid of all the contents in the expanded image folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same experience before, the temporary workaround is to delete the `BaseImage-14393` folder under `C:\programdata\Microsoft\Windows\Images\` manually.

Please notice that we need to get enough **security permission** to complete this operation, **please see my detailed steps in this [question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dce87a60-629a-4c11-bb7e-e0252311137f/uwpdesktop-app-converter-remove-old-baseimage-14316?forum=wpdevelop)**

Then I would suggest you reinstalling the Base Image.

I will inform the related team on this issue.

Comment: Very useful @Franklin Chen. The article you referred me to had the answer to my deletion problem (it might be a good idea to replace the image with one having the 2 check boxes selected).

Comment: @AndesUK If this is the right answer, could you please accept it:)

Comment: Have Microsoft deliberately over-complicated this whole process? Do you think they will produce a 1 step converter if this one is not used much?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure build version number of your operating system is same as base image. e.g. 17134

to ensure that use below command:

```
winver
```

If you installed wrong version try to remove existing image and reinstall correct version.

You can use below command which deletes all the expanded base images installed on your host machine.
Process may take a while.

```
DesktopAppConverter.exe -Cleanup ExpandedImage
```