# epanded base image error with reboot loop

Tags: desktop, bridge

I am stuck in a loop and cannot find a way to get out of it, i.e. stop the failing installation of the container. No matter how I cleared after reboot I get the same error again and again:

"warning 'W_EXPANDED_BASE_IMAGE_EXISTS': An expanded base image by name 'BaseImage-15063'
 already exists"

and

"DesktopAppConverter : error 'E_EXPANDED_BASEIMG_INVALID': ExpandedBaseImage at
'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-15063' is not a container image"

I renamed the BaseImage folder to force the process to start cleanly but that did not help; it again failed.

Now I have several huge BaseImage folders.

How do I get rid of these image folder/files which did NOT disappear with any clear command.
Trying to get rid of them as administrator running cmd.exe does not work either: access denied.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040940/desktopappconverter-dac-says-the-expanded-image-is-invalid-when-i-try-to-conv